# Google compute site can't be reached and telnet connection refused

Tags: debian, google-compute-engine

I have tried couple of things that were pointed out but cannot figure why I am not able to see my server page running on google compute machine running Debian.

I have installed nginx on the compute instance.

1. The output for `netstat -an | grep "LISTEN "` is as below

:

```
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:8998          0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:65001           0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.1:40333         0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:22              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:26              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN  
tcp6       0      0 :::8085                 :::*                    LISTEN  
tcp6       0      0 :::22                   :::*                    LISTEN  
tcp6       0      0 :::26                   :::*                    LISTEN
```

2. I have allowed both http and https in firewall
3. Here is my iptables

:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT)  
target     prot opt source               destination  

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT)  
target     prot opt source               destination  
DOCKER-ISOLATION  all  --  anywhere             anywhere  
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere             ctstate   RELATED,ESTABLISHED  
DOCKER     all  --  anywhere             anywhere  
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere  
ACCEPT     all  --  anywhere             anywhere  

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT)  
target     prot opt source               destination  

Chain DOCKER (1 references)  
target     prot opt source               destination  

Chain DOCKER-ISOLATION (1 references)  
target     prot opt source               destination  
RETURN     all  --  anywhere             anywhere
```

4. When I do telnet ip 80
   I get a connection refused error.
5. In my firewall rules, I have additionally added "udp:80"; allow for all ip's.
6. I navigate from GCP dashboard to the IP (https://35.202.214.186/) and I tried by removing https to make it http://35.202.214.186

   But I am not able to get to the site.

Request any help pointers .

Comment: You say you've added a firewall rule allowing udp port 80, have you also allowed tcp port 80? Telnet and http both use tcp.

Comment: Yes Robbie, I have both tcp port 80 and udp port 80

Answer (score 1):

On Compute Engine Vitural Machines, there are two separate firewalls that might need to be properly maintained. First one is internal firewall of the VM (iptables, ...) which usually you won't need to modify its rules as the default configuration is good for most applications.

The second firewall is [Compute Engine VPC firewall](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls#firewalls). This firewall come with default rules for HTTP and HTTPS protocols for [default VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networks-and-firewalls). If your VM is created on this default VPC network, then you will just need to verify the existence of the firewall rules and tag your VM with `http-server` and `https-server`. Otherwise, you should create appropriate rules to allow these protocols/traffic.

Comment: Update: [The default VPC network](https://cloud.google.com/vpc/docs/firewalls#default_firewall_rules) does not include anymore a rule for tagged http-server. It must now explicitly be defined.